# upgrade EF 6 (edmx) to EF core 2.0

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have application which is using angular 5 + EF 6 (edmx). I would like to change to Entity framework core.

Note: Entity framework core 2.0 and all other project are non core.

Regards

Comment: Awesome. But what is your question ?

Comment: I understand with reverse engineering I can create model classes base on exiting database table. Any time change in model class. I can run migration to sync database.

but not sure how I can deal with store procedure and views.

Also, please correct me if I am wrong. its a one time operation means I will generate model using Reverse Engineering and after that We will do change in model and update database. AI I right?

How we can work with SP and views?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you properly then

1. Use [scaffold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold) feature to build model classes from your database using command

> dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold
>   "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;"
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models

2. For [stored procedures](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx) or views you will need to do it manually generate empty migration and then add code there.

Example.

```
public partial class spGetStudents : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        var sp = @"CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStudents]
                    @FirstName varchar(50)
                AS
                BEGIN
                    SET NOCOUNT ON;
                    select * from Students where FirstName like @FirstName +'%'
                END";

        migrationBuilder.Sql(sp);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

Yes after you scaffold you will be able to modify models/entities and generate migrations but for sp and views you will do it manually.